# Multi-threading Form and user control

Tags: c#, multithreading

My visual studio project setup is like this:
On **Form**'s panel I add **User control(UC)** with the code:

in **Form**:

```
panel.Controls.Add(UC.Instance);
UC.Instance.Location = new Point(-(panel.Size.Width), 0);
UC.Instance.BringToFront();
roll_in();
```

in **User control**:

```
private static UC _instance;
public static UC Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new UC();
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

When I press a button on the **Form** the **User control** is added to the Form's panel and I use the following code to slide the **User control** to its position:

```
private void roll_in()
{
    while (UC.Instance.Location.X < panel.Location.X)
    {
        UC.Instance.Location = new Point((UC.Instance.Location.X + 2));
        UC.Instance.Refresh();
        if (UC.Instance.Location.X > -10)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

When I use the `roll_in()` all other functions and forms are waiting for this process to finish.

Is there a way I can slide the `User control` on another thread?
I tried calling `roll_in()` with creating another thread but it says the control was created on another thread.

Can someone help me on guiding me to the right path?
How can I do the "animation" without affecting other controls?

Thank you helping

Comment: Winforms + Animations  = WPF

Comment: Apart from that I would build an Animator class with a timer inside to process the animations. Animator.AnimateLocation( control: myControl, newLocation: new Point( x, y ), duration: TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 2 ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your blocking the UI thread by calling thread.sleep.  You generally don't want to do that for any reason.  async tasks were created to deal with UI issues like this.  Try this code.

```
private async void roll_in()
{
    while (UC.Instance.Location.X < panel.Location.X)
    {
        UC.Instance.Location = new Point((UC.Instance.Location.X + 2));
        UC.Instance.Refresh();
        if (UC.Instance.Location.X > -10)
            await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}
```

This should prevent blocking during your sleep cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Application.DoEvents()` inside your loop to process the winforms event queue at regular intervals:

```
private void roll_in()
{
    while (UC.Instance.Location.X < panel.Location.X)
    {
        UC.Instance.Location = new Point((UC.Instance.Location.X + 2));
        UC.Instance.Refresh();
        Application.DoEvents();
}
```

}

Info on `Application.DoEvents()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This seems to be an easy solution!
I included the WinFormAnimation library to do the animations!
But thank you for the solution, I tried with the DoEvents() and it works pretty neat!

Comment: Is there a way to add a delay?

Comment: @NikoLeben what do you want to delay? The call to `DoEvents()`?

Comment: Delay between UC.instance.location.x + 2, so the panel move speed would be slower

Comment: In that case a combination of hack's solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41590911/783836) that involves `async/await` and the use of `Application.DoEvents()` should achieve what you need. Just put the `Application.DoEvents()` call before or after the `await` call

Comment: I tried that :) Works great. I wish I could mark both as "Answer"

Comment: I tried! Upwote was recorded but not shown because less than 15 reputations